# Worthwhile to restrict direct access of theme files?

Tags: theme-development, security

I've run across the following snippet in themes from time to time:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) exit('restricted access');
```

It's at the beginning of some (all?) PHP files in a theme and it's supposed to prevent direct access of the file by nefarious sources.

I see that this isn't included in Twenty Ten or Eleven and I've never seen it recommended in official WordPress documentation. It seems like a good idea to me, but I also don't know enough about security to judge it and can't find much with Google.

Is this something I should have in my custom themes? If so, should it be in all PHP files or just some?

Comment: Just for later readers, this can be written shorter and nicer: `defined('ABSPATH') OR exit;`

Comment: or even shorter: `defined('WPINC') ? : die();` :P

Comment: I also wonder if it worth putting in some code like this just to avoid seeing the PHP errors about undefined functions in my error logs. Bots seem to like to directly hit these files sometimes and I get errors like 'Call to undefined function query_posts()' because the WP bootstrap hasn't been loaded

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Usually, you don’t need it. But … there is at least one edge case:

- If a theme file is a template *part*,
- *and* it is using global variables from the calling context (parent file),
- *and* [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is `on`,
- *and* it is just using these variables without any security check …

… an attacker can call this file, set the missing variables with `GET` or `POST` and make the theme file print those out. And then there *is* a security problem.

So … the best option is not a context check like the one from your example, but good code: avoid global variables, check their content before you print it out.

Comment: If a template part still contained at least one function call that would cause a PHP fatal error would this scenario still be possible?

Comment: @Chris_O Depends on the order of appearance.

Comment: Makes sense and totally agree on another reason not to use global variables between file calls.

Comment: It's always best to be safe than sorry. Too much security can't hurt, can it?

Comment: If you do everything right, you should not use code that isn’t needed. This question is the proof that it makes code harder to follow.

Comment: @fuxia Am I right if I say that I don't need to prevent direct access to a file that contains a class that is not instantiated in that same file? Even if the code in the file is executed, it would do nothing as far as I know.

Comment: @GerardReches Yes, exactly. :)