# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: theme-development, errors, headers

Hello WordPress Developers,

I got this erros messages when I check my site like below

mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mythemes

When I visite that url, it give me this message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in
>   /users/my-username/www/mysite-folder/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/index.php
>   on line 17

You know, the errors messages shouldn't give us like that, Am I right? And I googled for this and found no better solutions. Here are some steps that I have tried

- define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '228M' ); (it doesn't work)
- `<?php @get_header(); ?>` (it can make errors message disappear, but it is not the best solution.)
- `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 0); ?>` (it can also make errors disappear, but it is also not the right solutions.)
- So, I make new wordpress installation, it still give me that errors message

Please note: I don't install any plugins

What I understand on this errors, wordpress can't load

So, do you have better solution for this kind of errors? Please advice me, I have spent 3 hours for this.

Comment: Template files are not intended to be loaded directly and you shouldn't do it. If you do that, WordPress engine is not loaded and functions from WordPress, like `get_header()`, doesn't exist; that is why you get the error "Call to undefined function get_header()"

Comment: Hello @cybmeta ... I am agree on your talks, but you know, I don't wanna let that error happen like this, if hacker check like that, he would get **user name from the errors message url**.  Check my Question _errors message_. But you know, [www.wpbeginner.com] doesn't happen like that. That site can handle well, I think that they handle those files through **.htaccess**. How do you think?

Comment: You can use a firewall, like wpbeginner does, or just verifiy that WordPress is loaded at the top of the PHP file. For example with `if ( ! defined( ‘ABSPATH’ ) ) exit;`. Anyway, [you don't really need that](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62999/worthwhile-to-restrict-direct-access-of-theme-files).

Answer (score 2):

I got your point What you are trying to do. The solution to your problem is these lines of code to place above all the code of your index file or you may place it on all files of your theme.

```
<?php

// Do not allow directly accessing this file.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Traditionally, the check is for `WPINC` (because `ABSPATH` can be used by other applications/environments — the WordPress core developers ought to have named it `WP_ABSPATH` instead...)

Answer (score 0):

As per described by you I thought you had issue with the theme. Can you switch the theme ?

If its not possible with backend then Try with FTP just rename that theme folder to another name & then Look whats happen. If it still exist then you need to try it with disabling all plugin at once & then activate one by one to check which plugin will cause this issue.

I hope this will help you out in fixing this issue.

Comment: Hi @Ash, I have already made refresh installation with default theme, but it is still show the errors message, By the way, Have you also checked in your wordpress themes, I have checked most of the wordpress and over 75% of the sites show those kind of error messages.

That message can help hackers to know what is the username, Check comments discussion below my question.

Comment: Hi Can you add your header.php file code here so, i can verify that there is no cause of mistake on header.php file.