# Does My Child-Theme Functions.php Need if{die} Security In It?

Tags: php, functions, security

I'm new to PHP, but I've noticed just about every PHP file has a security snippet, "Die if not accessed in the correct manner" script at the beginning; **my question**, does a child-theme `functions.php` need something like this as well to make it secure?

**PHP:**

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( 'Direct Access Not Permitted' );
}
```

Comment: Check this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63004/43098)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it *need* it? Probably not (other than [this edge case](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63004/43098), props @bravokeyl). Should you add it? In my opinion, yes:

1. From a coding/architecture POV, you're declaring "this file needs WordPress".
2. Any direct hit to one of your theme's files (curious users, bots, "script kiddies" etc.) has the potential to leak a little bit of info (most likely filesystem) and/or litter your error logs (e.g. `Undefined function get_header in /bada/bing/bada/boom`)
3. Reiterating 1), it's just good practice.

**However**, I absolutely *hate* this:

```
die( 'Direct Access Not Permitted' );
```

IMO it should simply be:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
    exit;
```

There is just no point in having that "message". And I'm a big fan of `exit`. It communicates the fact that this is an *expected* possible scenario, and in that scenario, I simply wish to quit. I use `die` for "unexpected" scenarios, like filesystem write errors, database errors etc.

Comment: This is wrong. WP already masks these files. You're adding redundant functionality.

Comment: Sorry but no, it does not.

Comment: @JimMaguire you are mistaken, I think possibly you are thinking of WP htaccess rules, which 404 urls if the file does not exist. I just confirmed it on one of my sites, I get a 500 error on a file that I know doesn't have the check, and then a non-existent file in the same directory gives WordPress 404. I actually want to thank the dead medic, I don't use these checks currently but after reading this answer I will be in future, I hadn't really thought about it that way before (point 1)

Comment: Wow.. I think I was drinking when I made the above comment! Ok... 100% I am totally wrong that WP masks these files.

Comment: I think what my brain was trying to communicate is that this functionality is, or should be redundent. I've been doing OOP and my PHP files don't do anything at all if you load them directly. So I guess after years of programming I just forgot about this issue! Anyway... code in good OOP and you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: @JimMaguire "my PHP files don't do anything at all if you load them directly". Then you have display errors and/or error reporting switched off. And if you're going to make a claim like "and you don't need to worry about this" then post an answer detailing why.

Comment: LOL well... since I've said nothing useful... I'm going to delete my comments. Sorry guys.

Comment: Wouldn't `return` be better than `exit`, as it fails gracefully both if the file was accessed directly and if it was included from another script?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times there is no need to check for `defined( 'ABSPATH' )` in the child theme.

Answer (score 2):

No, `functions.php` would generate PHP fatals if loaded directly as it uses the WordPress API.

If `functions.php` tried to bootstrap and load WordPress however, then yes, it would be necessary, but if you've done that then something has gone **horribly wrong** and you need to start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Loading almost any (if not all) WordPress files directly will give nothing more than a white screen of death if you have your error reporting set properly. This is because it will trigger a fatal PHP error stopping the execution, and the correct public settings for error display is to not show them. However, if you are trying to mask that you are using WordPress or at least go to as great a lengths possible to do so, then you might want to make that check but inside the if trigger a 404 response code.

Comment: And fill your error log with messages, which you probably wouldn't want

Comment: A valid point @MrCarrot. However I have never really used those checks in my WP plugins or theme files, and nor have I ever seen them in any of the error logs I have examined so it is a matter of how many times you think people will try to visit site files directly, I personally see it as very rare.