# Clarity needed on usage of multiple 403 forbidden header() functions at the beginning of the plugin files

Tags: plugin-development, headers, http

Just see the following code snippet. I have came across this in one of the plugins that I am reading now.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  header( 'Status: 403 Forbidden' );
  header( 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' );
  exit;
}
```

I understand that this script is sending an forbidden 403 header response to the browser for unauthorized access. But why two 403 headers ? Is the second one kind of fallback to the first one ?

Comment: The second line is bogus. There is no good reason for it.

Comment: Actually I am confused, the second line is seen on most of the tutorials and even some of the highly voted questions here. I never found first one on any of the tutorials or answers here. Is your comment specific to wordpress ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper way to send a status (when WordPress is not available) is:

```
http_response_code( 403 );
```

See the [PHP Manual for its definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).

But in Plugin files, this should never be the "default" code on top of a file header. See *[Worthwhile to restrict direct access of theme files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/62999/73)* for a discussion.

In WordPress, use `status_header( 403 )` if you need it.

---

A note on the code you've posted:

```
header( 'Status: 403 Forbidden' );
header( 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' );
```

The first line is a "special" treatment for PHP running in CGI mode, the second is using a specific HTTP protocol version without any check. If the connection is over HTTP 2 or 1.1, this makes no sense.

Both are wrong, because the correct way to send the proper status with `header()` is using the second and the third argument of that function.

So this would work better:

```
header( 'Status: 403 Forbidden', true, 403 );
```

The second argument tells PHP to overwrite other headers with the same name, the third is for the real status. The code that you posted is a good **counter**-example. :)

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, I understand that I should use `status_header()`, a wrapper function for `header()`, But When I had a look at the source of `status_header()`, this function is preparing and calling original `header()` in `$protocol $code $description` format, which translates to `header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden')`, which you called a bogus line. Any other reason for calling it bogus ?

Comment: Because it repeats the functionality of the first line @NareshDevineni

Comment: Got it! So both of them are same. Since plugin was written by one of the best wordpress plugin authors, I thought there must be some hacky reason behind it !!

Comment: @NareshDevineni See my update for an explanation. I won't comment on "best plugin author" … :)

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you for the detailed explaination :)