# Throw 403 in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, errors

I'm having a little problem getting an information. In my plugin, I got a situation where I have to throw, in a very specific situation, a 403 error. But I can't find in the documentation if there is a recommended way to throw a 403, because WP LOVES wrap everything it's own way.

So! Do you know a way to trigger a 403 manually ?

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate, but I found my answer there too.

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit different, but the answer is very good in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

Is there any limitation/issue setting/thowing `403` the usual PHP way?

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
die('You are not allowed to access this file.');
```

Comment: Not ideal, see this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233381/clarity-needed-on-usage-of-multiple-403-forbidden-header-functions-at-the-begi

Comment: I don't know, that's why I ask. Maybe wordpress requires some pre-error handlings

Answer (score 0):

Modern PHP CMS/frameworks tend to abstract HTTP protocol as Request/Response.

WP comes from older times and has a very weak concept of HTTP response. Essentially it follow “classical” just throw stuff on a page model.

As such there is no “clean” way to work with headers in it.

De facto approach is just to use some appropriate hook to output custom headers and interrupt remainder of page load, if necessary. Most typical hook to do this on it traditionally `template_redirect`.