# Where i should not use if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }?

Tags: theme-development, security

I think this best way to prevent direct access..

```
<?php if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; }?>
```

i have used this on all my php files..can it create problems?
any files on WordPress theme i should not use it?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62999/worthwhile-to-restrict-direct-access-of-theme-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of that code is to prevent any PHP inside the file from being executed if the file is accessed directly outside a WordPress context. `ABSPATH` is defined by WordPress, so if it's missing when the file is accessed you can tell that it's not running in a WordPress context.

So the only place you wouldn't use it is in any file that you did need to access directly. There probably shouldn't be any such files in a WordPress theme or plugin. The most common example might be a file for handling AJAX requests, but in WordPress you should be using admin-ajax.php or the REST API for that sort of thing.

Comment: hi, What about the class files with namespace  it's not possible to put this code ? am i required to put this code there

Comment: It just needs to go after the namespace declaration, but before the class.

Comment: I just ran my plugin through the new block checker, and it's saying "FATAL ERROR: Found PHP call header(). This is likely to prevent your plugin from working as expected.
Block plugins should contain minimal PHP with no UI outside the editor. JavaScript should be used instead of PHP where possible."
And it's referring to precisely this code at the top of my plugin: 
`if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {  header('Status: 403 Forbidden'); header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); exit(); }`
Why would this be considered a potential blocker by the Block Checker?

Comment: well, just to add to my previous comment, WordPress developers on slack are suggesting to just simply use `exit()` (or `die()` ) without using `header()`. I guess that works just as well.